# Equivalent to background position percentage (%) in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, aspect-ratio, background-position

I have an SVG image that has the equivalent of `background-size: cover;` assigned to it using `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`.

However on phone devices less than 737px I'd like to move this image to the left within its container. If was was using the CSS `background` property I would just do `background-position: 85%;` or similar.

Is there an equivalent way of doing this with SVG images?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/Zqragv

Many thanks in advance for any help.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#section-1, .home-image-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.home-image, .home-image-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#home-image-1 {right: 0%}
```

```html
<section id="section-1">
  
  <div class="home-image-wrapper">
    
    <svg class="home-image" id="home-image-1" width="60%" height="100%">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.postimg.cc/9XdQKYF1/dimon-blr-309444-unsplash.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
    </svg>
    
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: An image a `x and a `y` attributes. Use these attributes to move your image as you like.

Comment: hi @enxaneta, this won't work - it slides the image on those coordinates, but doesn't change the part of the image being viewed which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setting position on svg elements

If you just want to change the svg element on a container (assuming <g> element). 
You can apply a simple transform on any element:

Example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300px">
  <!--black rect-->
  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" />
  </g>
  <!--blue rect-->
  <g transform="translate(20)" fill="#08a">
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="20" height="20" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: hi @persijn, I understand about transforms, but I want to move the image in its container on a window size < 737px, so that more of the right hand side of the image shows as per the CSS equivalent of `background-position` If you can relate your answer to my code please feel free in case I'm misunderstanding your answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SVG you can set the `viewBox` attribute. This defines the x, y, width and height of the visible part of the SVG. Let's say your `jpg` image has a width of 200 and a height of 100. In this case you set `viewBox="0 0 200 100"` by default to the `<svg>` element. On phone devices you can change the the `viewBox` value to something like `50 0 100 100`, which would only display the middle 100 pixels of the image.

You can find more on the `viewBox` attribute here: http://jonibologna.com/svg-viewbox-and-viewport/